# Wrong number of arguments Ruby class method

Tags: ruby, class, methods

```
class Array
def pairs(target)
  pairs_array = []
  self.each_with_index do |number, idx|
    self.each_with_index do |number2, idx2|
      if (number + number2 == target)
        pairs << [idx, idx2]
      end
    end
  end
  pairs
end
end

arr = Array.new
arr << "1" << "3" << "1" << "2" << "3" << "0"
puts arr.pairs(3)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from main.rb:42:in `<main>'
    1: from main.rb:36:in `pairs'
main.rb:27:in `pairs': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

I am relatively new to this so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but am I simply calling the method incorrectly? I am trying to call this and pass 3 as the target value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that your last statement in your pairs method is "pairs", which means that you do another (and this time recursive) function call. This function call happens without arguments, which causes the error.

I assume, that you actually want to put all your results into the variable "pairs_array" and return it (instead of "pairs").

Moreover

```
  if (number + number2 == target)
    #some code
  end
```

in combination with

```
arr = Array.new
arr << "1" << "3" << "1" << "2" << "3" << "0"
puts arr.pairs(3)
```

will always return false, since e.g. "1" + "2" is "12", whereas 1 + 2 is 3. => Take care of the data types you are using.

Comment: thanks, looks like some rookie mistakes. I changed my code but I am still just getting a bunch of numbers printed out, not the array pairs even though I'm using this:

pairs_array << [idx, idx2]

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that ruby is interpreting the line

```
pairs
```

as a function call to the function

```
pairs(target)
```

and not as a return statement. In order to fix this, rename your `pairs` array variable so that it does not match your function name. I believe you have already done this in the form of `pairs_array = []`, so instead of calling `pairs << [idx, idx2]`, you should be calling `pairs_array` << [idx, idx2] to store the pairs. Then, to return the array, call `pair_array` at the end of your function.

Another error is that you are passing in the numbers as strings and not ints, so when you are adding the two variable together, ruby is doing string concatenation, and not simply adding the two numbers together, to fix this, pass in the numbers as ints (i.e. remove the quotation marks around the numbers)

Comment: thanks, looks like some basic mistakes.

I tried editing the code and it's running now, but the output is just a bunch of numbers. They aren't in the [idx, idx2] pair array format I'm trying to specify. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: That is because you are using `puts` to print your output. `puts` adds a new line to the end of each argument if there is not one already. You can print your output in your desired format if you change `puts` to `p` or `print`, which does not add a new line. This should get you the format that you want. If you want to customize your output, I would suggest iterating through the `pairs_array` and printing out each pair how you want them to be displayed

Comment: oh, duh. Thanks!